# How much energy is lost between (solar panels+battery pack) & DC operated electronics due to conversion

Tags: ac-dc, conversion, power-dissipation

For the sake of simplicty;

I have solar panels generating Xvolt, Yamperage.

All of the power will be used by Xvolt devices.

But all of the house and device adapters are designed to use AC grid. So i need to convert Xvolt DC to AC220/110 volt (i dont know if AC volt changes the result in this application) and back to DC Xvolt again.

What percentage of the solar panels are used just for the conversion?

Comment: Draw a power flow diagram. Each conversion has an efficiency which depends on the specific device you are using. 80 to 90 percent efficiency is fairly common for good quality power converters.

Comment: @mkeith ~%15 percent lose to convert to ac. an other 15% of 85 = 12.5 back to the dc. i end up total 22.5% lose. this is pretty sad. i was expecting like 3-4% maybe 10% percent during storage.

Comment: I just began a blog describing the construction of my solar power station, and this is precisely the topic of the first post 01.  Feel free to take a look at http://www.sdsolarblog.com/starting-at-the-beginning-fun-with-a-reality-check/

Comment: Once you select real components, you may be able to look up their actual rated efficiency instead of using my 85% rule of thumb. Much higher efficiencies are possible, but you might have to search far and wide to find them.